# How to run batch file silently from tkinter

Tags: python, batch-file, tkinter

I want to run .bat file in tkinter silently without the the `cmd` popping out.The batch file runs alright but i want the `cmd` not pop out when i click on the button.

```
from tkinter import *
import os


def run_my_bat():
    os.system("mybatfile.bat")


root = Tk()


b = Button(root, text="run batch file silently", command=run_my_bat)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: see [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: @furas have tried subprocess.call("mybatfile.bat") but yet still the cmd pops up. using the subprocess module.

Comment: I don't use Windows I can't help you more. Using Google I found only [How to run a batch file without launching a “command window”?](https://superuser.com/questions/140047/how-to-run-a-batch-file-without-launching-a-command-window)

Comment: @Nae change the batch file name to what, can you explain it further for me

Comment: @NewpyBoi Not name. Read the link in [furas' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989210/how-to-run-batch-file-silently-from-tkinter?noredirect=1#comment82948852_47989210).

Comment: i checked the link and the examples was using .vbs code to achieve that

Comment: @NewpyBoi Yes but that vbs _calls_ a bat file _silently_. Do you _have_ to call .bat directly from python?